# How to get the the return type from a Func defined with a lambda?

Tags: c#, func

I have a static class that is responsible for holding some default data used by integration tests, previously it was using a `Dictionary<Type,object>` to store these values but because I need to be able to modify the objects I get without affecting future requests for the same object I've moved to using a `Dictionary<Type,Func<object>>` which works great.

Now in attempt to make using this static data store easier for the end user I've added another class to wrap the dictionary:

```
public class FuncValueDictionary
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _funcs;

    public FuncValueDictionary()
    {
        _funcs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        var key = typeof (T);
        if (_funcs.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)_funcs[key]();
        }
        throw new Exception("Dictionary does not contain a value for key: " + key);

    }

    public void Add(Func<object> value)
    {
        var key = value().GetType();
        if (_funcs.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            throw new Exception("Dictionary already contains value for key: " + key);
        }

        _funcs[key] = value;
    }
}
```

As is this works, but my problem with it is that it currently has to run the function when adding a new value (this is to get the return type of the function to be stored).

An example of adding a value:

```
var DefaultData = new FuncValueDictionary()
...
DefaultData.Add(() => new TestDataSet { SomeTestDataValue = "10.00" });
```

I am trying to find a method to determine this type from the function itself and I've tried `value.Method.ReturnType` but this is just returning `object`.

Is there anyway to get the correct type given the current step, or perhaps a different approach of achieving a static data store that returns a new instance everytime?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, you should define your Add method as: public void Add(Func<T> value)

Comment: I believe I have tried that but then `_funcs[key] = value` will fail because it is no longer a `Func<object>`

Comment: See tolanj's answer below, that should take care of the exception you were getting.

Comment: @Phaeze Yes, it is, so no, it won't fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Requires .Net >= 4.0**

Replace the Add method with a Generic:

```
public void Add<T>(Func<T> value) where T:class
{
    if (_funcs.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        throw new Exception("Dictionary already contains value for key: " + typeof(T));
    }

    _funcs[typeof(T)] = value;
}
```

*Apologies for pasting the earlier reply in hastily!*

Of course this isn't going to work for a value type

**NB**

*(stolen from a since deleted reply!)*

For .Net <= 4.0 you can do:

```
public void Add<T>(Func<T> value) where T:class
{
    if (_funcs.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        throw new Exception("Dictionary already contains value for key: " + typeof(T));
    }

    _funcs[typeof(T)] = () => (object)value();
}
```

Which removes the need for Generic variance

Comment: This will not work because `_funcs` is expecting a `Func<object>`

Comment: `_funcs[T]` is not going to compile. `_funcs[typeof(T)]` is not going to work either.

Comment: And I can't change the _funcs definition because i will be storing funcs for multiple different objects.

Comment: @Phaeze It will work just fine because `Func<T>` is covariant with respect to `T`.

Comment: @Phaeze It will work as of .NET 4.0.  It isn't an option if you're using an older version of the framework.

Comment: Sorry bit of a copy and paste mess, the code as updated does compile, doesn't futher 'infect' the class with generics but _IS_ limited to reference types due to generic covariance

Comment: Ok, so I guess I need to learn not to depend on ReSharper so much, I'm used to it suggesting the generic where clause for me ( it didn't this time); that does indeed make it work.